# Is there any characterization of cototients equal to prime powers?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Do we know something about numbers $x$ with

$x-\varphi(x)=p^n$ for some $n$ and prime $p$

Are there any for each prime $p$?

Comment: Cototients are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A051953 with many links. http://oeis.org/A053579 is composite numbers whose cototient is a power of two.

Comment: See also [A005278](https://oeis.org/A005278).  If the strong Goldbach conjecture is true, every odd number is a cototient.